# transfer cookies on a server/server request

Tags: node.js, cookies

In a universal app, i loose every users cookies on a server/server http request.
I have build a small nodeJS app that reproduce the thing:

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');

const server = require('express')();

server.use(bodyParser());
server.use(cookieParser());

server.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    httpOnly: false
}));

server.get('/set-cookies', (req, res) => {
  req.session.user = { name: 'john doe' };
  res.send('OK');
});

server.get('/a', (req, res) => {
  console.log('COOKIE IN A = ', req.cookies); // Cookies are here !

  const options = { credentials: 'include' };

  fetch('http://localhost:3131/b', options)
    .then( () => {
      res.send('OK');
    });
});

server.get('/b', (req, res) => {
  console.log('COOKIES IN B = ', req.cookies); // Cookies are lost ! How to get it back ?
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

server.listen(3131);
```

1) Hit GET /set-cookies
2) Hit GET /a (the cookies are here as expected)

Issue: When the /a controller will make an AJAX request to GET /b, it won't transfer the cookies, so the the route /b is unable to authenticate the user

How to transfer the users cookies on every requests ?
I have heard about "cookie jar" but i couldn't explain clearly what it is, and i didn't find any clean explanation on the web, if someone could share some knowledges about that, it would be great !

Comment: @MukeshSharma i started my message by "In a universal app", this is just a way to reproduce the technical case, of course i am not trying to use this code in my app...

Comment: Can you share the code, how you are calling `/b` from `/a` ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma a universal (or isomorphic) app is an application that run the same code on the client and the server side.
The code calling /b from /a is already in my post, it is the fetch() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whatwg-fetch` has option to send cookies by the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3131/b', {
   credentials: 'same-origin'
});
```

You can send manually cookie to the `fetch` by the following way.

```
server.get('/a', (req, res) => {
    console.log('COOKIE IN A = ', req.cookies); // Cookies are here !
    const options = { 
       'headers' : {
          'Cookie': req.headers.cookie
        } 
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:3131/b', options)
       .then( () => {
          res.send('OK');
       });
});
```